# Reordering an array: Even elements descending, odd elements ascending

Tags: java

I am trying to work out a solution. I have to order the elements in the array `a`,  such that `a[0]` is greater than `a[1]`,  `a[1]` is less than `a[2]`, `a[2]` is greater than `a[3]`, and so on...

Basically my method checks if the index is odd or even , and simultaneously makes a decision to swap elements to suit the criteria of the question.

I am getting the following output: `7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4`

```
public class ArrayRearrange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] a = { 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7 };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0 && a[i] < a[j]) {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
                if (i % 2 != 0 && a[i] > a[j]) {
                    int temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");

    }

}
```

Let me know if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Putting everything in the `main` method is bad practice, and is hard to maintain. Separate it into methods. This also removes duplicate code, such as when you swap values.
- `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` is generated in eclipse, and is only there to remind you to finish the method. It is not really to stay.
- Don't use one-letter variable names, except for counters. `a` should be `array`.
- Don't be lazy when you print something out. Still follow conventions.
- The two `if` statements are doing identical things. Combine them with an OR.

Final code:

```
public class ArrayRearrange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7 };

        rearrange(array);

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    private static void rearrange(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if ((i % 2 == 0 && array[i] < array[j]) || (i % 2 != 0 && array[i] > array[j])) {
                    swap(array, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  I was unsure about using the two for-loops basically which might be a problem if the input is quite large.